# Multiple process categories for Gnus

Tags: gnus, email, mu4e

When I process emails, 90% of my messages are either deleted or archived. When I get a big backlog, I work through the list marking a batch, then archiving or deleting them (`B del` or `B m`), and then moving on to the next batch. If I'm in the middle of marking a delete batch, I can't mark a message for archiving, or vice versa.

Is it possible to use two different marks in Gnus? It would be great if I could work down my list once, marking each message for either archiving or deletion, and then moving them all at once after I've finished. Is this possible? If not, is there another feature of Gnus that would help with this workflow?

## Update 23 October 2017

I've switched to mu4e for email, and it does allow for marking emails for deletion and archiving at the same time, with the actions executed together once you're finished. So if you need that feature, it's there in mu4e. As this might still be useful for Gnus users, I'll leave the question for now.